# Weights in Principal Component Analysis (PCA) using Psych::principal

Tags: r

I am computing a Principal Component Analysis with [this](https://uploadfiles.io/1o20z) matrix as input using the function `psych::principal` . Each column in the input data is the monthly correlations between crop yields and a climatic variable in a region (30) so what I want to obtain with the PCA is to reduce the information and find  simmilarities pattern of response between regions.

```
pc <- principal(dat,nfactors = 9, residuals = FALSE, rotate="varimax", n.obs=NA, covar=TRUE,scores=TRUE, missing=FALSE, impute="median", oblique.scores=TRUE, method="regression")
```

The matrix has dimensions 10*30, and the first message I get is:

> The determinant of the smoothed correlation was zero. This means the
>   objective function is not defined. Chi square is based upon observed
>   residuals. The determinant of the smoothed correlation was zero. This
>   means the objective function is not defined for the null model either.
>   The Chi square is thus based upon observed correlations. Warning
>   messages: 1: In cor.smooth(r) : Matrix was not positive definite,
>   smoothing was done 2: In principal(dat, nfactors = 3, residuals = F,
>   rotate = "none",  :   The matrix is not positive semi-definite, scores
>   found from Structure loadings

Nontheless, the function seems to work, the main problem is when you check pc$weights and realize that is equal to pc$loadings.

When the number of columns is less than/equal to the number of rows the results are coherent, however that is not the case here.
I have to obtain the weights for refering the score values in the same magnitude as the input data (correlation values).

I would really appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem

Comment: @sequoia I am afraid not sorry.